# Serializing only works when called in static main method of JavaFX App class

Tags: java, javafx, serialization, deserialization

I'm working on a project that uses JavaFX for the GUI (I know, non-serializable). I want to serialize objects such as my Users.

I'm not able to access the instance that JavaFX Application uses, but I have it associated in other classes.

For example - it is associated with my Controller class:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage){
         // ... assume controller loaded
         controller.setApp(this);
    }
}

public class Controller {
    MyApp app;

    public setApp(MyApp app){
        this.app = app
    }
}
```

Now when I go to serialize an instance of MyApp, I'm having difficulty. I found a slight trick (option 1), but it feels a little messy. I'd much rather do option 2.

**Option 1 [WORKS]** - create an additional instance in the main method.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage){
         // ... assume controller loaded
         controller.setApp(this);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyApp app = new MyApp(); // this is a different instance than javafx instance.
        launch(args)
        app.users = Controller.getUsers();
        writeApp(app);
    }
    public static void writeApp(PhotoApp photoApp) throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
        FileOutputStream(storeDir + File.separator + storeFile));
        oos.writeObject(photoApp);
        oos.close();
    }
}
```

Thus, option 1 essentially creates a new instance and copies stuff back and forth from the actual instance in `controller`.

**OPTION 2 [DOES NOT WORK]** - serialize the instance associated with the controller (since that is the actual instance JavaFX is using)

```
public class Controller {
    MyApp app;

    public void setApp(MyApp app){
        this.app = app
    }

    public void someAction(){
        MyApp.writeApp(this.app);
    }
}
```

---

When I do **Option 2** I get errors saying `Controller is not serializable`. I understand that it is not (which is okay), but I don't get that error in **Option 1**. In both options I'm  calling the same method with some instance of MyApp. I'm not sure why it works for **Option 1** but not **Option 2**.

Any reason why one option works over the other? How do most people do serialization of some of their objects when they use JavaFX?

Comment: This code won't compile as it is: `MyApp` is not a subtype of `PhotoApp` (whatever that is) so there is no `writeApp` method that can take an instance of `MyApp` as parameter. Even if that was a mistake when writing the question and changing some type names in the process there's still the fact that `MyApp` does not implement `Serializable`. The exception should happen in both cases AND it should complain about `MyApp`, not about `Controller`; in the first case the exception should happen after the JavaFX platform is shut down though...

Comment: If you just want to serialize your users, then I wonder why you dump your whole application for this purpose. Are you sure you know what you are doing? And once you have your dump, what would you then do with it? Do you assume that you can read that back in any reasonable way?